# Creating a window application that will perform certain action after every 10 minutes

Tags: c++, winapi, timer, timed-events

I was wondering would I still need to use a basic game loop for this particular operation?

Comment: If your application has a UI then it is required, if it is a console application then you don't need a message loop.

Comment: please note that by "game loop" I assume you mean a loop that runs as often as possible or at the VSYNC rate of the display, not event driven

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create a timer and perform that action on WM_TIMER message handling or on timer proc function you specify when creating the timer.

See [SetTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644906(v=VS.85).aspx) and [WM_TIMER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644902(VS.85).aspx).

Answer (score 4):

No, just use [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(VS.85).aspx), [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289(VS.85).aspx), and then use [MsgWaitForMultipleObjects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684242(VS.85).aspx) instead of GetMessage or PeekMessage in your event dispatch loop (typically in WinMain).

Answer (score 1):

You can implement timers more generally and portably by using the [Boost Asio](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) library.

[Here's](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) an example of creating an asynchronous timer.